# Calculated column in same query - Spark , Hive

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I need to use the previous value in the derived column to get the next result for the same column .

**1st occurrence of each name will be 1 by default**

derived column = num(i) + derived (i-1)

```
Name, Num, derived
A       0       1
A       1       2
A       0       2      
B       0       1
B       0       1
B       1       2
C       0       1
C       0       1
D       1       1
D       1       2
D       1       3
```

Below is my half code -- used window lag function but could not achieve

```
spark.sql("""
select

z.name as name,

z.num as num,

case

  when z.row_num='1' then '1'

  else (lag(num) over(partition by z.name order by name))

  end as derived

from

(select name,num,row_number() over(partition by name order by name) as row_num

from result)z""").show()
```

Comment: Could you also provide the original result table? see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you using mysql, or hive?

Comment: @GMB - I am using Hive

Answer (score 1):

You can use session variables

```
select
  z.name as name,
  z.num as num,       
  @derived := case
  when z.row_num='1' then '1'
  else num + @derived
  end as derived
from
  (select name,num,row_number() over(partition by name order by name) as row_num
  from result)z,(SELECT @derived:= 0) d1
```

Which would give you

> ```
> name | num | derived
> :--- | --: | :------
> A    |   0 | 1      
> A    |   1 | 2      
> A    |   0 | 2      
> B    |   0 | 1      
> B    |   0 | 1      
> B    |   1 | 2      
> C    |   0 | 1      
> C    |   0 | 1      
> D    |   1 | 1      
> D    |   1 | 2      
> D    |   1 | 3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d47211fbef3ac83d331bd8ba6636c7d)*

Answer (score 1):

For this to be solvable, you need a column that can be used to *order* the records. I assume that such a column and is called `id`.

In hive, you can use `row_number()` and do a window `sum()` as follows:

```
select
    name,
    num,
    sum(case when rn = 1 then 1 else num) over(partition by name order by id) derived
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
```